# Renderproblem with QOpenGLFunctions

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, render

I wanted to program a custom OpenGL Widget inside a QML application to plot data with MathGL. 
To do this i took a look at the Scene Graph example at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html 
I then adapted the code to my needs and then the problem occurred, that the Image only flashes one rendercycle and after that doesn't appear anymore.
Following are the important functions and bindings.

class GLRenderEngine : public QObject, public QOpenGLFunctions

```
void GLRenderEngine::render()
{
    if(!m_bInit)
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        m_pGraph = new mglGraph( 1 );
        m_bInit = true;
    }
    glViewport(m_Viewport.left(), m_Viewport.top(), m_Viewport.width(), m_Viewport.height());
    m_pGraph->Clf();
    //Graph stuff ...
    m_pGraph->Finish();
    if(m_pWindow)
        m_pWindow->resetOpenGLState();
}
```

class GLWidget : public QQuickItem

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(QQuickItem *parent) : QQuickItem(parent)
{
    m_pRender = 0;
    connect(this, &QQuickItem::windowChanged, this, &GLWidget::handleWindowChanged);
}

void GLWidget::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win)
{
    if(win)
    {
        connect(win, &QQuickWindow::beforeSynchronizing, this, &GLWidget::sync, Qt::DirectConnection);
        connect(win, &QQuickWindow::sceneGraphInvalidated, this, &GLWidget::cleanup, Qt::DirectConnection);
        win->setClearBeforeRendering(false);
    }
}

void GLWidget::cleanup()
{
    if(m_pRender)
    {
        delete m_pRender;
        m_pRender = 0;
    }
}

void GLWidget::sync()
{
    if(!m_pRender)
    {
        m_pRender = new GLRenderEngine();
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, m_pRender, &GLRenderEngine::render, Qt::DirectConnection);
    }
    m_pRender->setViewportSize(boundingRect());
    m_pRender->setWindow(window());
}
```

QML-File

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import GLWidget 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 320
    height: 480

    GLWidget{
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: glView
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7)
        radius: 10
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "white"
        anchors.fill: label
        anchors.margins: -10
    }

    Text {
        id: label
        color: "black"
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        text: "The background here is a squircle rendered with raw OpenGL using the 'beforeRender()' signal in QQuickWindow. This text label and its border is rendered using QML"
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 20
    }
}
```

I also noticed, when i used QQuickFramebufferObject the image disappeared after a call to update() or a resize event of the window, even though the render function is being called, so my guess is that either the buffers aren't being updated or something else with qt is off.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem i switched to the QQuickFrameBuffer implementation and removed any glClear commands i had been using inside the render function, while the Clear Flag of the base class QQuickItem is enabled.
It now works like a charm.